# Are there any effects of fasting on cognition?

Tags: intermittent-fasting

I'm curious as to whether intermittent fasting, like eating once a day (warrior's diet?) or eat stop eat has an impact (especially negative) on your mental performance.

I'm aware of a study showing during the month of Ramadan, when people fast all day, the number of traffic accidents increased. But I thought that since Ramadan is fasting of food and water, the dehydration could potentially impact your mental state.

In another example, children who eat breakfast tend to do better at school than those who do not. This would be a model of eat stop eat, because (I'm assuming) the children skipping breakfast eat only lunch and dinner, so thats a 16 hour fast and 8 hour feeding window. Is the result true because low income children cannot afford to eat breakfast, and they tend to do worse in school? Or is it because the feeling of hunger, (which they are not used to, which also would be almost nonexistent in a ketogenic, low carb diet) is distracting them from their school work?

The reason I am curious is that fasting-based diets are coming into vogue for weight loss and lean muscle growth, and I'd like to know the effect this might have on other aspects of my life.

Answer (score 2):

Low income children cannot really be compared with people who fast on purpose. Children of families of low-income do not have much to eat(even when they want to and therefore never fully recharge their bodies). I assume you are blessed enough to have much to eat.

The following study studies the month of Ramadan and how it affects Muslim students (in countries that do not observe/change their exam schedule for that month). http://personal.vu.nl/b.vander.klaauw/ramadan.pdf

```
"The most likely explanation for the reduction in the academic achievement of Muslim 
Students due to Ramadan exposure is observance of the fast. Previous research documents 
that observing "the Ramadan fast, leads to reduced activity, less desire to study and lower 
concentration ability among a majority of the subjects.(Afifi, 1997)
```

From personal experience however:

Many of the top scorers (academically) I know personally including some family members do not eat breakfast. I think it depends on the person (and you will need time to get used to it.)

Comment: so I guess its really about personal preference and how you react to hunger/lack of food right?